# How to ensure that IPv6 temporary address is the preferred address?

Tags: windows, networking, ipv6, privacy

Opening https://www.google.com/#q=what+is+my+ip in any browser shows `xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx8e` (my permanent ipv6 address, see below), even though windows is configured to use [ipv6 privacy extensions](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4941).

After a reboot or resetting the interface temporary addresses are used for some time, but after one expires and is replaced with a new preferred one they are not used as source address for outgoing connections any more.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetIPv6Protocol

UseTemporaryAddresses         : Always
MaxTemporaryDadAttempts       : 3
MaxTemporaryValidLifetime     : 7.00:00:00
MaxTemporaryPreferredLifetime : 1.00:00:00
TemporaryRegenerateTime       : 00:00:05
MaxTemporaryDesyncTime        : 00:10:00

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-NetIPAddress | Format-Table

ifIndex IPAddress                                       PrefixLength PrefixOrigin SuffixOrigin AddressState PolicyStore
------- ---------                                       ------------ ------------ ------------ ------------ -----------
5       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx9f                  128 RouterAdv... Random       Deprecated   ActiveStore
5       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx92                  128 RouterAdv... Random       Preferred    ActiveStore
5       xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xx8e                   64 RouterAdv... Link         Preferred    ActiveStore
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, this is a bug in Windows and is still broken in build 16299.64.  It is a nasty privacy problem since it works until the temporary IPv6 address is first updated can lead people to believe they aren't leaving a unique 64-bit identifier (the lower half of the permanent IPv6 address) wherever they go.

I found this post here on superuser after poking a year-old thread on TechNet regarding the same problem:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/57925467-2b8d-4c2d-b1f2-b0402581a30e/how-does-one-get-the-system-to-actually-use-the-ipv6-temporary-addresses?forum=win10itpronetworking

EDIT:  This problem seems to have been fixed sometime between build 16299 and 17127.

Comment: The windows 10 april 2018 update fixed it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This has been working for me for the past week or so. I believe the issue must have been fixed in the March 13, 2018 KB4088776 Cumulative Update, as it was installed on my systems shortly before I noticed that IPv6 privacy addresses work properly now.

There's nothing specific to IPv6 in the [official list of "Improvements and Fixes"](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4088776/windows-10-update-kb4088776), but it may be part of the general "security updates" bullet point.

Comment: KB4088776 is installed but it's still using the permanent address after a day. Definitely not fixed.

Comment: @the8472 Interesting. Now I'm quite curious as to what changed to make it start working for me.